# Gridviews with Array of arrays

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and am refactoring some code. I am calling some Oracle stored procedures to return data that comes back like so:

```
Array
([ATTENDING] => Array
    (
        [0] => Person 1
        [1] => Person 2
        [2] => Person 3
    )

[PREVIOUS_YEAR] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 2
    )
    ...
)
```

I'm trying to use this array within Gridview, but finding that my columns are blank, I tried this:

```
  $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
  'allModels' => $data,
  'sort' => [
    'attributes' => ['ATTENDING',
                     'PREVIOUS_YEAR',
                      ...
                   ],

  ],
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 10,
],
]);
```

It returns 12 rows (the number of columns the query returns) but there are only three rows returned in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to adjust my `oci_fetch_all` statement so it returned by row rather than column. So hope it helps someone else

```
oci_fetch_all($refcur, $data, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```